# TCP communication between Raspberry Pi with Win10 IoT and a Xamarin Android Application

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying to develop a simple TCP server/client between a Raspberry Pi 3 with Win 10 IoT and an App developed with Xamarin Android.
I'm using my Samsung S9+ to debug the App.
The server is the Raspberry.

In the Raspberry i have put this code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.StartServer();
    }

    private async void StartServer()
    {
        try
        {
            //Create a StreamSocketListener to start 
            //listening for TCP connections.
            Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener socketListener = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener();

            //Hook up an event handler to call when connections are received.
            socketListener.ConnectionReceived += SocketListener_ConnectionReceived;

            //Start listening for incoming TCP connections on the specified port. You can specify any port that's not currently in use.
            await socketListener.BindEndpointAsync(new Windows.Networking.HostName("localhost"),"9999");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    private async void socketListener_ConnectionReceived(Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener sender, Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        //Read line from the remote client.
        Stream inStream = args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inStream);
        string request = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

        //Send the line back to the remote client.
        Stream outStream = args.Socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outStream);
        await writer.WriteLineAsync(request);
        await writer.FlushAsync();
    }
```

And in the Xamarin App i have this:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{

    EditText txtInvia;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        Button btnInvia = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnInvia);
        Button btnConnetti = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnConnetti);
        txtInvia = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtInvia);

        btnConnetti.Click += BtnConnetti_Click;
        btnInvia.Click += BtnInvia_Click;
    }

    private void BtnInvia_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void BtnConnetti_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.StartClient();
    }

    public static bool PING(string ipAddress)
    {
        // Ping's the local machine.
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(address);

        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}", reply.Address.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
            Console.WriteLine("Don't fragment: {0}", reply.Options.DontFragment);
            Console.WriteLine("Buffer size: {0}", reply.Buffer.Length);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reply.Status);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private const int PortNumber = 9999;
    private void StartClient()
    {
        string localAddr = "192.168.137.1";
        if (PING(localAddr))
        {
            try
            {
                MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask(localAddr, PortNumber, string.Format(txtInvia.Text + "\r\n"));
                myClientTask.Execute();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Where MyClientTask is this:

```
public class MyClientTask : AsyncTask
{

    string dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    string response = "";
    string msgToServer;

    public MyClientTask(string addr, int port, string msgTo)
    {
        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = port;
        msgToServer = msgTo;
    }

    protected override Java.Lang.Object DoInBackground(params Java.Lang.Object[] @params)
    {
        Socket socket = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

        try
        {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.OutputStream);

            if (msgToServer != null)
            {
                dataOutputStream.WriteBytes(msgToServer);
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream =
                    new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead;
            System.IO.Stream inputStream = socket.InputStream;

            /*
             * notice:
             * inputStream.read() will block if no data return
             */
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                byteArrayOutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                response += byteArrayOutputStream.ToString("UTF-8");
            }

        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.PrintStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.ToString();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.PrintStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (socket != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    socket.Close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.PrintStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

When in the MyClientTask I create the new socket with this instruction:

```
socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
```

If I connect my phone to the HotSpot created by the Raspberry I got this error

```
IOException: Java.Net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.137.175 (port 9999) from /:: (port 37604): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused) ---> Android.Systems.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

If I connect my phone to the WiFi and ths Raspberry via Ethernet at the same router the Xamarin App stay blocked in the creation of the socket since it goes in timeout.

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks! <3

edit: 
I see that the Ip address of the Raspberry in the App was wrong so now is correct and I my app is blocked in the same way like ethernet connection.

Comment: ['connection refused'](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message) basically means that the connection is (actively) refused. This is different than a timeout. It usually means that there is a firewall, or there is no process running on the remote machine that can handle the request.

Comment: @GolezTrol Now i have edited the code but i'm blocked for the timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can use **BindServiceNameAsync** method instead of **BindEndpointAsync** method to do not limit traffic to an address or an adapter.

Secondly, you need to firewall block for the server port you used, the following command could allow the access.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Tcp Server Port(9999)" dir=in protocol=TCP localport=9999 action=Allow
```

The last, you need to specify the [device capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enable-device-capabilities) of your app. The `Private Networks (Client & Server)` capability should be enabled for Tcp server.

There is a StreamSocket sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket) you can refer to. It shows how to use the StreamSocketListener class to create a TCP socket to listen for an incoming TCP connection.